# javafx TextArea.appendText() throws exception when send a message with TCP

Tags: java, javafx, tcp

Hi everyone thank you for the help beforehand. I wanted to create a simple chat Programm to see how the .net library in java is working. Because I have worked in java only with the javafx interface I decided to use this instead of awt or swt. I'm not sure but maybe the way I give the same controller access to two different .fxml files coud cause the problem.

In the Main.java I load the .fxml files that I use to create the GUI. The logic is mainly in the other classes.

Main.java

```
package sample;

import TCP.TCP_Server;
import UDP.UDP_Server;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private AnchorPane rootLayout;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");
        initTest();
    }

    public void initTest()
    {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("test.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Chat Name");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);


            Controller controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setStage(primaryStage);
            controller.setMain(this);
//Here I want a Username before someone can send messages or login
            initNamePanel(dialogStage, controller); 

            dialogStage.showAndWait();
            //controller.setServer(server);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
//only a panel to enter a chatname
    public void initNamePanel(Stage primaryStage, Controller controller){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("ChatNamePanel.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Chat Name");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);

            Controller crt = controller;
            crt = loader.getController();
            crt.setChatNameStage(dialogStage);

            dialogStage.showAndWait();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import TCP.TCP_Client;
import TCP.TCP_Server;
import UDP.UDP_Client;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.Main;

import java.net.SocketException;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Label nameLable;
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtArea;
    @FXML
    private TextField inputField;
    @FXML
    private TextField chatnameField;

    private Stage chatNameStage;
    private Stage stage;
    private TCP_Server server;

    private TCP_Client client;

    private Main main;

    public Controller(){}

    public void setStage(Stage stage){this.stage = stage;}
    public void setChatNameStage(Stage stage){this.chatNameStage = stage;}

    @FXML
    public void OKbutton()
    {
        String msg = inputField.getText();
        if(msg != "" || msg != null) {
            client.SendToServer(msg);
//empty the input Field 
            inputField.setText("");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void closeButton(){
        client.close();
        stage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    public void setChatName(){
        String name = chatnameField.getText();


        client = new TCP_Client();
        client.setController(this);
        if(name != null || name != "") {
            client.setChatName(name);
            (client).start();
            chatNameStage.close();
        }
        else
            System.out.print("Enter a Name");
    }
    @FXML
    public void closeNamePannel(){
        chatNameStage.close();
        stage.close();
    }

    public void setRecivedMessage(String serverMassege){
        txtArea.appendText(serverMassege); //the exception occures here but the massege was send with the correct login massege so serverMassege is not null

    }


    public void setMain(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }
//newClient is not in use anymore but I dont want to delete it because of reasons
    @FXML
    public void newClient() {
        main.initTest();
    }

}
```

TCP_Client.java

```
package TCP;

import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.privateutil.PolicyUtils;
import sample.Controller;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class TCP_Client  extends Thread{
    private static int serverPort = 4711;
    private static String host = "localhost";
    private Socket myClient;
    private BufferedReader input;
    private BufferedWriter output;
    private Controller controller;
    private boolean wait = true;

    private String chatName;

    public void setChatName(String chatName){
        this.chatName = chatName;
    }

    public TCP_Client(){
        try {
            myClient = new Socket(host, serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setController(Controller newController){
        controller = newController;
    }
    public void run(){
        createSocketStream();
        login(chatName);
        RecieveFromServer();
    }

    private void createSocketStream()
    {
        try {
            output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(myClient.getOutputStream()));
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myClient.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Don't know abot host: "+host);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

//is called when I press the OK Button 
    public void SendToServer(String msg){
        try {
            if (msg == null || msg == "")
                return;

            System.out.print(msg);
            output.write(msg);
            output.newLine();
            output.flush();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    //needs to run in a seperate thread so I need to put this in the run methode as I understand it
    private void RecieveFromServer(){
        try {
            String response;
            while (wait) {
                response = input.readLine();
                controller.setRecivedMessage(response);
                if(response == "Quit")
                    break;
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void close(){
        try {
            wait = false;
          //  System.out.print("Log out");
            output.write("--QUIT");
            output.newLine();
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            myClient.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void login(String name){
        try {
           // System.out.print("Sending: " + name);
            //  output.writeChars(msg);
            output.write("--NAME"+name);
            output.newLine();
            output.flush();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

TCP_Server.java

```
package TCP;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TCP_Server extends Thread{
    private String line;
    private LinkedList<BufferedWriter> outList;
    private LinkedList<Socket> clientList;
    private LinkedList<String> usernameList;
    Socket actClient;
    private BufferedWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;

    public final static int port = 4711;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket sSocket;
        LinkedList<BufferedWriter> outs = new LinkedList<BufferedWriter>();
        LinkedList<Socket> clients = new LinkedList<Socket>();
        LinkedList<String> userNames = new LinkedList<String>();

        boolean runServer = true;
        try {
            sSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            //runServer
            while (System.in.available()==0){
                Socket clientSocket = sSocket.accept();
                (new TCP_Server(outs, clients, userNames, clientSocket)).start();
            }

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print(e);
        }

    }

    private TCP_Server(LinkedList<BufferedWriter> outs,  LinkedList<Socket> clients,
                       LinkedList<String> userNames, Socket clientSocket){
        outList = outs;
        clientList = clients;
        usernameList = userNames;
        actClient = clientSocket;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(actClient.getOutputStream()));
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(actClient.getInputStream()));
            line = in.readLine();
            //check if name is allready used
            for(String s : usernameList){
                if(s.equals(line.substring(6)) || line.substring(6).length()<=1){
                    System.out.print("Name schon vergeben oder zu kurz");
                    return;
                }
            }
            //the registration
            if(line.startsWith("--NAME")){
                synchronized (clientList) {
                    for (BufferedWriter o : outList) {
                        //I need the name of the user after the --NAME
                        o.write(line.substring(6) + " hase joint the chat");
                        o.newLine();
                        o.flush();
                    }
                }
                usernameList.add(line.substring(6));
                outList.add(out);
                clientList.add(actClient);
            }
            //when --Quit is send checkout the user
            while ((line =in.readLine()).startsWith("--QUIT") == false){
                if(line != "" || line != null) {
//tell everyone that the user hase left the chat
                    synchronized (clientList) {
                        for (BufferedWriter o : outList) {
                            o.write(line);
                            o.newLine();
                            o.flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //chekout
            outList.remove(out);
            clientList.remove(actClient);
            synchronized (clientList) {
                for (BufferedWriter o : outList) {
                    o.write(line.substring(6) + "hase left the chat");
                    o.newLine();
                    o.flush();
                }
            }
            actClient.close();

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The other clients recive the message that I send over the server but I cannot append the text to the TextArea. 
Following Exceptions are thrown from the client that recives the message:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Controller.setRecivedMessage(Controller.java:88)
    at TCP.TCP_Client.RecieveFromServer(TCP_Client.java:87)
    at TCP.TCP_Client.run(TCP_Client.java:43)
```

I know where the error is but how can I solve it?
The Code hase some other flaws but I want to deal with it when I solved the problem here described.

Comment: Are you using the same controller class for the controllers for two different FXML files? That gets really confusing: it's too difficult to keep track of what is initialized in each of the instances of the controller class. And it's not really clear what is happening in `initNamePanel()`: you do `crt = controller;` and then *immediately* set `crt` to something else: `crt = loader.getController()`. What is supposed to be happening there? Probably to fix this you need to start by organizing the code and cleaning it up so that it is more logical; then you can see where the problem is.

Comment: loader.getCotneroller() nothing else as giving the Controller class access to manipulating the .fxml file as I understood it. So I don't think I initialised it twice with loader.getController() but I will check it.

Comment: Of course you initialized it twice. You did `crt = ...` twice.

Comment: oh I thougt if I do it like that than it is in java the same as when I write

Comment: in c++ void foo(Object* o){ Object* oo = o;}

Comment: I think you are completely missing the point. You do `crt = something ; crt = somethingElse ;`. This is the same in all languages and it doesn't matter if you're talking about pointers, references, or values : if you assign something to a variable and immediately assign something else to it, the first assignment is redundant.

Comment: And then if `crt = controller;` is not doing anything, there seems to be no reason at all to pass `controller` to `initNamePanel(...)`: you are not using it in that method. So, again, it's not really clear what you are doing in that method.

Comment: If I untangle your code: the NPE occurs in `Controller.setReceivedMessage()`, so presumably txtArea is null. `setReceivedMessage(...)` is called from `TCP_Client.receiveFromServer(...)` on the instance field `TCP_Client.controller`, which is initialized by a call to `TCP_Client.setController(...)`. The only place I see a call to `TCP_Client.setController(...)` is in `Controller.setChatName()` where you call `client.setController(this)`. The `setChatName()` method is annotated `@FXML`, so presumably is a handler method for some event, defined in FXML.

Comment: So: which FXML file has a control with a handler method `setChatName()`, and does that FXML file define a text area with `fx:id="txtArea"`? If not, that is why you are getting the null pointer exception. Again, you appear to be using the same controller class for two different FXML files, which is leading to the confusion that is causing the NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James_D allready suggested in a comment the use of the same controller for two different .fxml files caused the problem. The only thing I did was to create a new ChatNameController class and the only thing this class does is checking if the chatname is correct and give this information (String) to the Controller class.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting NullPointerException on below line.

```
'txtArea.appendText(serverMassege);'
```

It seems that something wrong with textArea attribute.

can you check in your XML file txtArea attribute name should be exactly same as ID in the XML file?

Comment: the reason is that I used the same controller class for both .fxml files. I created the .fxml file with a scene builder so  I don't think that the ID in my XML file is incorrect because I give the xml Element the ID over the scene builder.